# What does it mean when a Facebook post has no application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook Graph API documentation indicates that there is an application element of the post object:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

But we often don't see an application element at all.  When that happens, does it mean that the post was created through a browser on the Facebook web site?

Here's an example:
https://graph.facebook.com/7976226799_10151201757386800?access_token=XXXX

Comment: Why did this get -1'd?  The answer is not necessarily obvious.  Twitter always specifies an app ("web" when the tweet goes through the Twitter web interface). Facebook API docs don't say one way or the other, so I'm not going to assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's what it means. If there wasn't an Application it means it was made with Facebook's own interface.